# Intersection of Zermelo-Fraenkel universes containing all ordinals

Tags: set-theory

I am reading my first Set Theory book (Set Theory and the Continuum Problem, Smullyan, 2010) and I find the subject pretty interesting. I am not a professional mathematician and can only study maths in my spare time.

After presenting ordinal numbers and transfinite recursion, the author presents the class $R_\Omega$ of all sets with rank. $R_\Omega$ is defined as the union of a sequence of sets $R_\alpha$, $\alpha$ being an ordinal number. The $R_\alpha$'s are constructed recursively by taking the power set of the previous set in the sequence or, in the case of limit ordinal, the union of all previous sets. A set has rank $\alpha$ iff it lies in $R_{\alpha+1}-R_\alpha$.

As an exercise the author asks the reader to show that $R_\Omega$ is the intersection of all subclasses $C$ of $V$ ($V$ being The universal class, the class of all sets) such that $C$ is a Zermelo-Fraenkel (ZF) universe containing all ordinals of $V$.

Previously the author has shown that $R_\Omega$ is in fact a ZF universe and since each ordinal has rank itself it is clear that $R_\Omega$ includes the intersection. However it is not clear to me why the converse is true. Why should $R_\Omega$ be the smallest ZF class containing all ordinals?

Now I am new to the subject and doing a little bit of research I can see that what the author calls $R_\Omega$ is often called V in literature and can be approached by different ways that I do not understand at this point. But I hope this question makes sense, any help appreciated.

Comment: Isn't the answer simply that ZF proves the existence of each $R_{\alpha}$ so that any ZF universe must contain each $R_{\alpha}$, and therefore any such universe must contain at least $R_{\Omega}$?

Comment: I was tempted to think like this too. But in this book I have mentioned, the author at some point discusses ZF universes not containing all ordinals. So that would contradict the fact that any ZF universe contains each $R_\alpha$.

Comment: That sounds odd. What are you assumption on the class of all sets? Normally $R_\Omega$, also known as the "von Neumann universe" is the *largest* class model of ZF. Whereas $L$, Gödel's constructible universe, is the smallest.

Comment: The book, as far as I understand it of course (disclaimer), assumes the following axioms: $V$ is transitive, swelled, contains the empty set and the pairing, union, power and substitution axioms hold. According to the author these axioms make $V$ a ZF universe. The author at some point also proves that IF $V$ is well-founded, then $V=R_\Omega$, which kind of suggests that if $V$ is NOT well-founded then this is not necessarily the case and therefore we only have $V$ includes $R_\Omega$ in general.

Comment: I think it makes sense if Smullyan asked whether $R_\Omega$ is the intersection of all class models of ZF, which contains all ordinals and is *closed under the true powerset* (i.e., power set operation over $V$.) Or ZF you mentioned is possibly the *second-order* ZF. (ZF means a first-order theory in usual.)

Comment: The exercise is stated exactly as I wrote. No mention of true powerset or second-order. Maybe these things are implicit for the author but in general the book is quite explicit and clear so I would be surprised if that were the case.

Comment: What is the definition of "swelled"?

Comment: Swelled means that every subclass of a set is a set (a set being understood as an element of $V$). The author calls a class which is both swelled and transitive as "supercomplete", I don't know if that is a more common term.

Comment: In the presence of the usual separation axioms this just means that a subset of an element is an element, and this is means that the power set is correct, as suggested by @Hanul.

Answer (score 2):

I glimpsed your textbook (but an older version. 2010 version is not available to me) and I found that Smullyan and Fitting distinguish ZF-universes and *first-order* ZF-universes. They stated separation axiom and replacement axiom as a second-order form, and differentiate these axioms with its first-order counterparts.

(Note that some textbooks (e.g., Jech) also use this kind of description for first-order Separation Replacement, although most of them give detail on its first-order nature.)

That is, Smullyan and Fitting assume *second-order* ZF. ZF-models in your textbook are closed under an arbitrary subset of their elements (or *swelled* under their terminology.) Hence they are closed under the true powersets, as I and Asaf mentioned in the comment.

Then the proof of your problem is direct: If $W$ is a ZF-model which contains every ordinal, then $R_\alpha\subseteq W$ for every $\alpha$ by induction on $\alpha$. Hence $V\subseteq W$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately I am unfamiliar with some of the terminology (e.g. 1st vs 2nd order versions of ZF). So I need some clarification. The author assumes the Power set Axiom (the power set of a set is itself a set), is that what you mean by "true" power? What is meant by "model"? Finally could you detail the transfinite induction? I can't see how to use the fact that all ordinals are elements. If we assume that $R_\alpha$ is a set, then by power axiom $R_{\alpha+1}$ is also a set and by transitivity $R_{\alpha+1} \subseteq W$ but I am not sure the first assumption can be made?

Comment: @Breizh Later and previous chapters of your textbook would mention what a first-order logic and a model are. (e.g., Chapter 2 explains what a first-order logic is.)

Comment: True power set means a power set operation defined over $V$, not another (first-order) ZF-model. There is no reason that the power set operation defined over $M$ coincides with that of $V$. The transfinite recursion argument is *really* direct: imagine a set $x$ which is a subset of $R_\alpha$. Then you can say $x\in W$ (why?) Could you conclude $R_{\alpha+1}\subseteq W$ from that?

Comment: Well if $x$ is a subset of $R_\alpha$ and $R_\alpha$ is a set (element of $W$) then by the "swelled" axiom $x$ is an element of $W$. But I cannot assume that $R_\alpha$ is a set, can I? And then by power axiom $R_{\alpha+1}$ is a subclass of  $W$. And still, why do we need $W$ to contain all ordinal numbers in this argument? How would the argument be modified if $W$ only contained a proper subclass of all ordinal numbers?

Comment: @Breizh I forgot that we have to ensure $R_\alpha\in W$. If $R_\alpha\in W$, then $P(R_\alpha)\in W$ since $W$ is a ZF-model. If $\alpha$ is a limit ordinal, then $R_\alpha=\bigcup_{\xi<\alpha}R_\xi\in W$. The fact that every ordinal is a member of $W$ is needed to ensure the limit case works.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution to my own question, based on the comments I got.

I want to show that $R_\Omega$ is in the intersection of all subclasses $C$ of $V$ which are ZF universes and contain all ordinals. To show this it suffices to show that $R_\alpha \subseteq C$ for all the considered $C$'s and all ordinals $\alpha$, since $R_\Omega$ is the union of the $R_\alpha$'s.

Consider a ZF subclass $C$ of $V$ containing all ordinals. First we show that $R_\alpha \in C$ by transfinite induction on $\alpha$.

- $R_0 = 0 \in C$ by the Empty Set Axiom.
- If $R_\alpha \in C$ then $R_{\alpha+1} = P(R_\alpha) \in C$ by Power Axiom.
- Now the limit case. Suppose that for every $\beta < \alpha$ we have $R_\beta \in C$. Define the function $F$ from $\alpha$ to $C$ such that $F(\beta)=R_\beta$, for all ordinals $\beta \in \alpha$. Since $C$ contains all ordinals it contains $\alpha$ so $\alpha$ is a set and we can use the Substitution Axiom to conclude that $F''(\alpha):=\{F(\beta) | \beta < \alpha\}$ is a set. Then by Union Axiom $\cup F''(\alpha) = R_\alpha$ is a set, i.e. $R_\alpha \in C$ which concludes the induction.

Now for every ordinal $\alpha$ we have $R_\alpha \subseteq R_{\alpha+1}$ and $R_{\alpha+1} \in C$. So by the Swelled Axiom, $R_\alpha \subseteq C$, which is what we wanted.

Please let me know if you spot mistakes.